# Ionic app after deploying gives ReferenceError: Promise is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making my first Ionic app. The part of it use promises.

The example below illustrates the problem.
(In the view I have a button which kicks off $scope.test which executes testProm() function).

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    testProm();
  }
});

function testProm() {
  console.log('1. Function testProm starting...');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('2. Hi from Promise');
    var something = ' Some text ';
    resolve(something);
  }).then(function(something) {
    console.log('3. Hi again. Something is: ' + something);
  });
}
```

Everything works fine in browsers (Firefox, Chrome) and while deployed to Sony Xpreria tablet with Android 5.1.1.

The problem starts when I deploy to cheap Woxter QX103 tablet with Android 4.4.2.
In this case when I try to run my function it gives me following error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at testProm (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:825:14)
    at Scope.$scope.test (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:29:5)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26457:15), <anonymous>:4:203)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62386:9
    at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29158:28)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29257:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62385:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16583:21)
    at triggerMouseEvent (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2948:7)
    at tapClick (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2937:3)
```

What is strange I use CouchDB also using promises and it works just fine. What do I do wrong? 
This is my very first javascript and I pretty inexperienced with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it is simply not supported in older browsers, as shown [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises). In my experience, this can easily be resolved by using Angular's own implementation of Promises, which looks like this:

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (okToGreet(name)) {
        resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
      } else {
        reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
```

You can find more information about the `$q` service in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). So in your code, if you were to replace `new Promise` with `$q` and make sure that you define it as a dependency, you should be good to go.